# Manage data inside a buffer

Tags: c, file, buffer

I'm using this code to read a file into a buffer. The file is full of `structs` of `evaluacion` type (including some `char` and `int` variables).
Now I have the whole file in a buffer, how can I find the values of one variable in the buffer now?
For example `buf.notamedia < 4`. There are supposed to be many of them inside the file.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
int revisanotas(int fd)
{
    int nbytes = 1;
    int nbytese = 0;
    evaluacion buf;
    struct stat datos;
    fstat(fd, &datos);

    printf("Size of file =  %d \n", datos.st_size);
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(datos.st_size);
    int actual = read(fd, buffer, datos.st_size);

    printf("actual = %d\n", actual);

    if (buf.notamedia >= 4.5 && buf.notamedia < 5)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Any idea is very welcome

---

I'm doing as you said, but I'm only getting one iteration, I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

```
evaluacion* buffer=(evaluacion*)malloc(datos.st_size);
int actual = read(fd,buffer,datos.st_size);

printf("Number of structs = %d", (datos.st_size/(sizeof(evaluacion))));

for (i=0;i<(datos.st_size/(sizeof(evaluacion)));i++);
{
printf("Notamedia = %f\n",buffer[i].notamedia);
if (buffer[i].notamedia >= 4.5 && buffer[i].notamedia < 5)
{
printf("Notamedia = %f\n",buffer[i].notamedia);
}
{
}
}
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to put your read in a loop to read the entire file.

Also, it may be easier just to mmap() the file.

Comment: @Suppressingfire: he does a single read to get the whole file, as of the time when the fstat() function executed, anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest to define the buffer as a pointer to the data structure and use that to dereference the data (although you should ensure the file size is a multiple of the structure size).

i.e.

```
evaluacion* buffer = (evaluation*)malloc(datos.st_size);
if(buffer[0].notamedia >= 4.5)
```

You can then increment the index to access other structures you loaded.

Comment: Thanks tyranid for the answer. In that case, should I read one struct by one, and read the file every time I search for the variable?
What I need to do is to read the file only once, make the operations with the structs in memory and then write the file to the disc again only once.

Comment: If the buffer contains the evaluacions one after the other, then you can just look at buffer[1] for the 2nd one, buffer[2] for the 3rd... Just make sure to divide st_size by sizeof(evaluacion) to make sure you don't go past the end of the file (i.e., don't let your buffer index be greater than st_size/sizeof(evaluacion).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments, I think I solved the problem, I modified the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
int revisanotas(int fd)
{
int nbytes=1;
int nbytese=0;
int i=0;
int n=0;
struct stat datos;
fstat(fd, &datos);
evaluacion buf;
printf("File size =  %d \n", datos.st_size);
evaluacion* buffer=(evaluacion*)malloc(datos.st_size);
int actual = read(fd,buffer,datos.st_size);

do 
{
i++;
if (buffer[i].notamedia >= 4.5 && buffer[i].notamedia < 5)
{
n=n+1;
/*printf("Notamedia = %f\n",buffer[i].notamedia);
*/
buffer[i].notamedia=5;
}

}while (i<(datos.st_size/(sizeof(evaluacion)))); 
nbytese=write(fd,buffer,datos.st_size);
printf("Written bytes = %d\n",nbytese);
return(n);
}
```

Now, If the condition is matched, I'm modifying the buffer. Once I read all the structs I write the file in the disk again, but I still have a problem, every time, instead of write the file in the same position, seems like I'm adding the same information after the old one, so if I read the file once I get 3.5Mb, two times 7MB and so on :S.
Any idea what can I do?
Thanks

Comment: I think I solved it with lseek, placing the pointer at the beginning before write.
lseek(fd,OL,SEEK_SET);

:)